# retrieve field of type class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class that is going to be passed into a function and it will be defined as follows:

```
class ayy{

String blah;
Class a;
Class b;

}
```

I want to be able to invoke the getSimpleName() method on the classes a and b. Currently I am doing it as follows:

```
Class c = (Class)argument; // Where argument is the "ayy" class
c.getField("a").getSimpleName();
```

But this gives me an error saying "getSimpleName()" is not defined for type field.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a method directly on an object that results from reflection, such as you're doing with `Field`, as if it were a reference variable of the desired type.

Instead, you'll need to call [`getDeclaredField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-), because [`getField` only gets `public` fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField-java.lang.String-).  Also, you'll need to [`get()` the value of the `Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-), passing in an instance of the `ayy` class, which will return the value of the `Field`.  Then you'll need to cast it to a `Class`, because `get()` returns an `Object`.  Then you can call `getSimpleName()`.

```
Class<?> classOfA = (Class<?>) c.getDeclaredField("a").get(anAyy);
String simpleName = classOfA.getSimpleName();
```

You'll also need to catch the various reflection-related exceptions that may be thrown.

Comment: Would I be able to invoke methods as normal on classOfA? Such as classOfA.getFields()?

Comment: Yes, once you have `classOfA`, you can continue with reflection and call any method of `Class` on it, e.g. `getFields`.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Class field MergerArgument.a to java.lang.Class`

MergerArgument is just another class with 3 fields (2 of these fields are of type Class)